# Does apache royale support two-way data binding now?

Tags: apache-royale

As title. I did not find any example or blog about two-way data binding. If not support, only can handle ui change event, or have some better way to update model(value object) ?

Answer (score 0):

we still don't support the Flex `@` coding style for two-way databinding. You can use event listeners as a workaround. In **MXML** the following notation is an option.

```
<fx:Binding source="voObj.firstName" destination="myTextInput.text" />
<fx:Binding source="myTextInput.text" destination="voObj.firstName" />
```

We expect to implement `@` at some point. As always, volunteers are welcome to make it happen sooner :).